# Avro GenericRecord deserialization not working via SpringKafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm trying to simplify my consumer as much as possible. The problem is, when looking at the records coming in my Kafka listener:

`List<GenericRecord> incomingRecords` the values are just string values. I've tried turning specific reader to true and false. I've set the value deserializer as well. Am I missing something? This worked fine when I use a Java configuration class, but want to keep consolidated to this application.properties file.

## application.properties

```
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="${SASL_ACCESS_KEY}" password="${SASL_SECRET}";
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

#### Consumer Properties Configuration
spring.kafka.properties.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.properties.value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
spring.kafka.properties.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy

spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=
spring.kafka.properties.specific.avro.reader=true
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*

logging.level.org.apache.kafka=TRACE
logging.level.io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry=TRACE
```

## consumer

```java
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${topic}", groupId = "${group}")
    public void processMessageBatch(List<GenericRecord> incomingRecords,
                                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) List<String> topics,
                                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets) {
        currentMicroBatch = Stream.of(currentMicroBatch, incomingRecords).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (currentMicroBatch.size() >= maxRecords || validatedElapsedDuration(durationMonitor)) {
            System.out.println("ETL processing logic will be done here");
        }
        clearBatch();
    }
```

I notice when I use:

> spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
> spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

I get the following error:

> 2020-12-02 17:04:42.745 DEBUG 51910 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] i.c.k.s.client.rest.RestService          : Sending GET with input null to https://myschemaregistry.com

```
2020-12-02 17:04:42.852 ERROR 51910 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: null

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition my-topic-avro-32 at offset 7836. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "src" is null
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._assertNotNull(ObjectMapper.java:4735)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3502)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:270)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:334)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:573)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:557)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:149)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:230)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:209)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:241)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:102)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:81)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1268)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3600(Fetcher.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1492)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1600(Fetcher.java:1332)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:645)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:606)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1263)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1225)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:949)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. Debugging deep into the rest client for confluent, I was hit with a 401 (terrible logs btw)

I needed to add this:
`spring.kafka.properties.basic.auth.credentials.source=SASL_INHERIT`

since I'm using SASL auth and needed registry to inherit the SASL config I added up above. fun stuff..

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
for me I just needed to set the protocol of the schema-registry url from `http://` to `https://` and it worked.

@Ryan answered gave me a clue.

Comment: Glad I could help!